# Equivalent of "git update-index --skip-worktree <file>" for future contributor pulls?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got some files in my project that get changed by every developer, but I don't want them to be added with `git add *`. Running `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>` works for me, but I want a way for it to affect everyone who pushes code as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a setting you can easily distribute to everyone like `gitignore`, it needs to be set locally by the developer who cloned the repository. Could you please add some more context about what these files are? Are these configuration files? There could be another way to solve the problem rather than relying on git.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to ignore changes to tracked files in Git.  From [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes):

> Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked. This does not work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against the index when performing certain operations. In general, Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate solutions are recommended.

As the documentation recommends, you should use a different solution, such as creating a template file that is checked in and copying it to an ignored name and modifying that, or using a set of defaults that are checked in that can be overridden with an additional config file that is not.